# Keep only existing file paths from list in boost build/b2/jam

Tags: list, bjam, boost-build, b2

If I have a variable containing a list of file paths that may or may not exists, how can I filter-out the files that do not exists ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `glob` rule from `path`

[link to documentation](https://www.bfgroup.xyz/b2/manual/main/index.html#bbv2.reference.modules.path)

example:

```
import path ;
local CANDIDATE_FILES = a.cpp b.cpp ;
local EXISTING_FILES = [ glob $(CANDIDATE_FILES) ] ;
```